# kernel: hpet1: lost 19 rtc interrupts

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, interrupt

I have this error that flooding my syslog every day. As a solution on arch linux forum is hpet=disable in kernel command line, but I think it is a bad idea and I searching for another solution. Is there any other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I had the same issue on the same machine. Applied below option and now the dmesg is not showing that error anymore.

From here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=124908

> Try to disable hpet with hpet=disable via the kernel command line. It will fall back to a less nice (but not seemingly broken) clocksource if available.

Search web on how to add kernel boot option.
For grub, here is the article I used: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/kernel-boot-parameter-edit/

Try it first at boot time, by adding a temporary boot option (explained in the howtoforge article).